# Smooth slide image one way

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-transitions

I have image which is symmetrical and I want to move it infinitly from right to left smoothly. I tried to use TranslateAnimation but first I have to properly set my image which is quite difficult mainly because this image is using all screen width and I should set negative margins. Are there any other solution? And is there a possibility to move image without moving ImageView?

Comment: you can use pager also for this. here is demo http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/

Comment: Yeah, the 'proper' way would be to use a ViewPager to swipe images.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I made it by my own and the solution is to put 2 images on each other and then measure screen width and use 2 TranslateAnimation, one from screen width to 0 and second one from 0 to -screen width:

```
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, -screenWidth, 0, 0);
    TranslateAnimation anim2 = new TranslateAnimation(screenWidth, 0, 0, 0);
    anim.setDuration(5000);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim2.setDuration(5000);
    anim2.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim2.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    backgroundOverlayImage.startAnimation(anim);
    backgroundOverlayImage2.startAnimation(anim2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, -1000, 0, 0);
        anim.setDuration(1500);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        anim.setRepeatCount(0);
        anim.setInterpolator(this, Android.Resource.Animation.LinearInterpolator);
```

**Edit:**
at the end don't forget `imageView.startAnimation(anim);`

Comment: There are few problems with this solution, it can show blank space when image is moved too much and I have to set negative margins to make it working.

Answer (score 0):

Though you got answer, [try](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) this repository, this will solve all your queries regarding slides and also will add custom animation to your views!

[image: Preview]